# Не работает redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Почему такой редирект отрабатывает:

```
RewriteRule ^ru/special/$ specials/ [L]
```

а такой нет:

```
RewriteRule ^ru/special/132/?a=ent&nid=117$ specials/ [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что `RewriteRule` не работает с частью URL, называемой [QUERY_STRING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

Для манипуляции с `QUERY_STRING` нужен `RewriteCond`.
Поэтому второй вариант можно разобрать так:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} a=ent&nid=117
RewriteRule ^ru/special/132/$ specials/ [L]
```